# How can I use rules method with formRequest in Laravel Js Validation?

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-validation

This is my Request page: [request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdrX1.png)

```
{!! \JsValidator::formRequest('App\Http\Requests\Backend\UserRequest', '#my-form') !!}
```

im trying like this with Laravel JS Validation. But i have some errors like this: [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMDdM.png)

I'm using the form like this:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['class' => 'form-horizontal form-bordered', 'route' => ['admin.user.update', $user->id], 'method' => 'PATCH', 'id' => 'my-form']) !!}
```

Comment: What package are you using for validation?

Comment: https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation

Comment: It would seem your rules method in your form request object is not returning anything, likely because you have not accounted for `GET`.  If a get request is outputting the form, the method is going to be equal to `GET` even if the form's method is `post`.

Comment: im added how i using form at question

Comment: The problem is a `GET` request is being used to generate the form.  When the js validation package is trying to reach into the `rules` method in your form request object, the method is `GET`.  Try adding `case 'GET':` right above `case 'PUT':`.

Comment: It works now. But i don't want to get same rules on the PUT or PATCH methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
if (\Request::segment(3) == "create")
    return [
        'name'                  => 'required',
        'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.\Request::segment(3),
        'password'              => 'required|min:5|confirmed',
    ];
else
    return [
        'name'                  => 'required',
        'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.\Request::segment(3),
        'password'              => 'min:5|confirmed',
    ];
```

Maybe it is solves other people's problems. Thanks for interesting my questions...